# Is there a way to force Doxygen to show only cyclic header dependencies?

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I'm using the Doxygen GUI frontend app on Windows, and for the Diagrams topic, I choose the 2 "Include dependency graphs" and "Included by dependency graphs" options under the "Use dot tool from the GraphViz package" option. However, I don't need to see everything; I'm only interested in the circular header dependencies. Is there a way to tell Doxygen to show only the dependency cycles?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm only interested in the circular header dependencies" do you mean the self dependent or also more complex like `A -> B -> C -> A` or ... ? Just showing this type of dependencies is not a task of doxygen.

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's exactly what I meant, both self dependent and `A -> B -> C -> A` cases. Oh I see. Then it means that I'll have to write my own tool (I've looked around, and Doxygen is like the closest tool that meets my need). Thanks!